# Drawing the turtle module

Tags: turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

I do not understand this part of the code. `if abs(pos()) < 1:` what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abs(pos())` means absolute position. `if abs(pos())<1:` means you come back to starting point. Hope it clarifies to you.

Answer (score 2):

This code draws a star with red lines & filled with yellow.  The `abs(pos()) < 1` statement is used to compare the current turtle location with the original starting turtle position after executing each iteration of the `while` statement.  If the turtle position is less than 1 unit away, the `while` statement terminates and the `end_fill()` statement executes to complete the yellow color fill.

Comment out the `if` statement and watch what happens, also, experiment with different numbers in the `abs(pos())<1` expression, including 10, 20, 30, etc. to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use 'if turtle.heading() == 0:'.

If my understanding isn't too incorrect,
when 'turtle.heading == 0' then the turtle is facing 'east',
the direction it started drawing from.
This has worked for all the angles I've tried so far.

Using  'if abs(pos()) < 1:' ...
I can only draw images at the origin (0,0).

(Maybe there's a way to draw images at
other locations using 'if abs(pos()) < 1:'
but I haven't figured out how.)

Using  'if turtle.heading() == 0:'
I can draw images anywhere on the screen.

```
import turtle


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Drawing Geometric Shapes")

Leo = turtle.Turtle()
Leo.color('red', 'yellow')
Leo.speed(0)
```

#=====================================

```
def star(x, y, length, angle):

    # Draw star
    Leo.penup()
    Leo.goto(x, y)
    Leo.pendown()
    Leo.begin_fill()
    while True:
        Leo.forward(length)
        Leo.left(angle)
        if Leo.heading() == 0: #===============
            break
    Leo.end_fill()

    # Move pen off-screen
    Leo.penup()
    Leo.goto(-500, 0)
```

#=====================================

```
#   (  x,    y,  length, angle)
star(-270,  180,  100,    120)
star( 190,  200,  100,    160)
star(-270, -220,  100,    100)
star( 190, -190,  100,    170)
star(-160,  0,    350,    178)
```

#=====================================